# Working with an accelerator dataset in chunks

Tags: python, bigdata

We have a huge dataset in [accelerator](https://www.exax.org) where we need to perform some very expensive operations on each row.
If we wanted to work on the entire set in one go it would take weeks, so instead we want to take a small fraction at a time, say 1% and work on that during the nights.

Currently, all data is in a single dataset. What are the options for setting up jobs to work say 
rows 1 million to 2 million?

I can see three possible paths:

#### Keep dataset

1. Add a new column, fill it with None
2. Add a method which skips the first n+million rows and then updates that column for the next million

My problem with with approach is that it requires skipping n^2 / 2 rows, and we have a lot of rows

#### Create a chained dataset.

Iterate through the main dataset and add each row to a new dataset, making new datasets and chaining with the old one each 1 millionth row

This one should be faster, it requires more space but it will remain useful down the line.

#### Use a magic method to split dataset into chains

Just use a method from the standard library to split the dataset into a chain, this one would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you would import your data as a chain with reasonable chunks from the beginning, but if that's not practical for some reason, I think splitting the dataset you have is the way to go. (As you say, n^2 isn't good if n is not small.)

A standard method for doing this should probably be added. Here's what such a method might look like:

```
options = dict(lines_per_dataset=int)
datasets = ('source', 'previous',)

def prepare(job, slices):
    previous = datasets.previous
    writers = []
    for sliceno, linecnt in enumerate(datasets.source.lines):
        writers.append([])
        for ix in range(0, linecnt, options.lines_per_dataset):
            previous = job.datasetwriter(
                columns=datasets.source.columns,
                previous=previous,
                name='%d_%d' % (sliceno, ix,),
                for_single_slice=sliceno,
            )
            writers[-1].append(previous)
    return writers

def analysis(sliceno, prepare_res):
    per = options.lines_per_dataset
    writers = iter(prepare_res[sliceno])
    for ix, data in enumerate(datasets.source.iterate(sliceno)):
        if ix % per == 0:
            write = next(writers).get_split_write_list()
        write(data)

def synthesis(prepare_res):
    # We want the last one to be the default dataset
    for r in prepare_res:
        for dw in r:
            ds = dw.finish()
    ds.link_to_here()
```

Note that I'm not propagating the hashlabel here, as that would leave each dataset with data in just one slice if the source is hash partitioned.

Comment: Shouldn't we reset previous in the top loop in prepare?
Also, I can't find anything in the documentation about `columns=datasets.source.columns`

Comment: We want a single chain, so no, we should not reset previous.

Comment: That explains why i ended up with 48 chains, 
Alright, so adding slices is to a dataset is also done by setting the earlier slice as previous? I take it the order here cant really matter since its the last dataset in the chain for one slice thats being used as previous for the first dataset in the chain of the next slice?